# nullを返す可能性のあるJava関数の返り値をOptionでラップする方法

Tags: scala

nullを返す可能性がある関数をOptionで受け取る場合、例えば

```
val fuge=Option(nullablefunc())
def twice(one:Option[Int])={
    one.map(2*)
}
val result=twice(fuge.asInstanceOf[Option[Int]])
```

Option(null)の場合、型がOption[Null]=NoneになるのでOption[Int]にするためキャストしてますけど

```
fuge.asInstanceOf[Option[Int]]
```

Optionがnullを受け取る可能性がある場合、上記の方法以外にnullを受け取れる方法があるんでしょうか。？

Comment: 「もうちょっといいやり方」というのは具体性がありません。例えば今のコードのどこが問題と考えていて、どのようになるといいと考えているかを明示すると、回答者の助けになると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　とりあえずキャストしてしまってるのが気持ち悪いなぁと感じています。

Comment: すると、hogeメソッドがどういうシグネチャのメソッドで、なぜそこでキャストが必要になってるのか、がわからないと答えられないですね
(hogeメソッドがちゃんとしてれば、必ずしもキャストは発生しないはず？)

Comment: replで書いてる時に、あれ？　そういえばjavaから呼んだメソッドがnullを返す場合、option受け取る関数はどうすればいいんだ？って悩んでしまってて。。

Comment: nullablefunc() が String を返す API だった場合、 Option(nullablefunc()) は Option[String] と型付けされます。よって null を返す可能性のある Java API を Option() でくるんでも asInstanceOf は必要にならないと思います。

Comment: 上のIntまたはnullを返すnullablefuncってのがそもそもおかしかったですね
どうもIntegerとIntとintがごちゃごちゃになってました
java.lang.Integerを返す型である必要がありました。
option(nullablefunc())はoption[Interger]になってこれはキャストが必要ですね。
でもval fuge:Option[Int]=Option(nullablefunc())
がヌルポになる。。

Answer (score 2):

`Option[Int]`型として、`null`あるいは`Int`を返すjavaの関数`nullablefunc()`の返り値を使いたいということでしたら、

```scala
val fuge:Option[Int]=Option(nullablefunc())
```

のようにシグネチャを付ければ解決すると思います。

Comment: 参考: http://kmizu.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/05/08/162615

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ただnullablefuncがIntegerを返す場合
ヌルポになってしまいます。。

Comment: 下で既に @nazoking さんが指摘されていますが、`Integer` -> `Int`の暗黙変換が`Option.apply`適用前に起こってしまうようですね。

同解答にあるように一旦`Option[Integer]`にしてから変換を噛ませればヌルポも起きません。（が、もうちょっと綺麗な書き方ができないものか、悩みどころですね……）

Comment: ありがとうございます。　たしかにもうちょっと綺麗な書き方したいですねぇ

Answer (score 1):

scala では Integer => Int 時にnullだとNullPointerExceptionを出すみたいです。

```
scala> val x:java.lang.Integer = null
x: Integer = null

scala> val y:Int = x
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at scala.Predef$.Integer2int(Predef.scala:357)
  ... 43 elided
```

なので上記のコードは

```
val fuge = Option[Integer](nullablefunc()).map(Integer2int)
def twice(one:Option[Int])={
    one.map(2*)
}
val result=twice(fuge)
```

のようにしないと NullPointerException が出てしまいますね

Comment: ありがとうございます！
intergerをintで受け取る事はあんまりなさそうですが
もしあったらうっかり変換を忘れそうです。。

Comment: `public Integer nullablefunc();` の時に `Option[Int](nullablefunc())` すると暗黙変換が入って実際には `Option[Int](Integer2int(nullablefunc()))` となるので NullPointerException がでるみたいです。 scala でIntegerを使う事は少なくてjavaでIntgerを使う事は多いので、 javaのライブラリを使うときは結構あるんじゃないですかね……